# How to correctly use KKT conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a positive definite matrix. Then find

\begin{equation}
\max_{|x_i|\leq1}x^TAx
\end{equation}

Here I want to use KKT conditions to show that $|x_i|=1$ is an optimal solution.

Derivative of objective function $\nabla f(x^*)=2Ax$ and derivative of inequality constraint function is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_i\nabla g_i(x^*)=[\pm\mu_1 \quad \pm\mu_2 \quad \cdots \quad \pm\mu_n]'$, so KKT conditions are

\begin{equation}
2Ax-[\pm\mu_1 \quad \pm\mu_2 \quad \cdots \quad \pm\mu_n]'=0;
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mu_i\geq0;
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mu_ig_i(x^*)=0;
\end{equation}
So if $2Ax$ is non-zero element-wise, then $\mu_i \neq0$, thus $g_i(x^*)=0\quad$ i.e. $|x_i|=1$ is optimal solution.

But how to show that $2Ax$ is indeed non-zero element-wise?

Comment: If $(Ax)_i = 0$, you do not need $|x_i|=1$. What makes you think $|x_i|=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: I did a simulation that shows optimal solution is always at $|x_i|=1$. Even though, $(Ax)_i=0$ for some $x$, you can change signs of some $x_i$ to get $(Ax)_i\neq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: If $A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1  & -1\\-1  & 2 &1 \\-1  & 1  &2\end{bmatrix}>0$, then $Ax=[0 \quad 2 \quad 2]'$ for $x=[1 \quad 1\quad 1]'$, but $Ax=[4\quad-4\quad-4]'$ for $x=[1 \quad -1\quad -1]'$.

Comment: are you saying the KKT conditions are not sufficient for optimality?

Comment: no, I am saying that to use KKT conditions, I have to show that there exist $x\in\{\pm1\}^n$ such that $(Ax)_i\neq0$ for all $i$. But I don't know how. I want to show that $\mu_i>0$ for all $i$